# Synchronous System.import() in ES6

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs, es6-module-loader

Is there a way for `System.import('module')` to load 'module' synchronously?
Just like with `require('module)` in nodejs..

I was hoping to do something like this:

```
let defaultConf = {port: 5555}; 
let envJS = './conf/env/' + process.env.NODE_ENV + '.js';
let conf = System.import(envJS);
_.merge(default_conf, conf);
export default defaultConf;
```

Comment: Not with `System`, no. But given that you *are* using node (with `process.env.NODE_ENV`), you can simply use `require`. Or `JSON.parse(readFileSync(…))`, after all.

Comment: @Bergi Guess I'll just have to use JSON.parse() then..thanks!

Comment: Why? `require` is not forbidden in ES6 code, and seems to suit your purpose.

Comment: Just a matter of preference, not to mix up import styles

Comment: Well if you mix asynchronous with synchronous imports, you might just as well styles :-)